# How to shutdown an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, shutdown

Whenever I call `shutdownNow()` or `shutdown()` it doesn't shut down. I read of a few threads where it said that shutting down is not guaranteed - can someone provide me a good way of doing it?

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as accepted

Answer (score 94):

The typical pattern is:

```
executorService.shutdownNow();
executorService.awaitTermination();
```

When calling `shutdownNow`, the executor will (generally) try to interrupt the threads that it manages. To make the shutdown graceful, you need to catch the interrupted exception in the threads or check the interrupted status. If you don't your threads will run forever and your executor will never be able to shutdown. This is because the interruption of threads in Java is a collaborative process (i.e. the **interrupted** code must do something when asked to stop, not the **interrupting** code).

For example, the following code prints `Exiting normally...`. But if you comment out the line `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) break;`, it will print `Still waiting...` because the threads within the executor are still running.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) break;
            }
        }
    });

    executor.shutdownNow();
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)) {
        System.out.println("Still waiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting normally...");
}
```

Alternatively, it could be written with an `InterruptedException` like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {Thread.sleep(10);}
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //ok let's get out of here
            }
        }
    });

    executor.shutdownNow();
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)) {
        System.out.println("Still waiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting normally...");
}
```

Comment: do you know if shutdown also initiates `Thread.interrupt()`, from the Java API it does not seem that `shutdown` interrupts the threads ?

Comment: @Bionix1441 No it doesn't. `shutdownNow` does though.

Answer (score 36):

The best way is what we actually have in the javadoc which is:

> The following method shuts down an **ExecutorService** in two phases,
>   first by calling `shutdown` to reject incoming tasks, and then calling
>   `shutdownNow`, if necessary, to cancel any lingering tasks:

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
    pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    try {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
        if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
            if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        pool.shutdownNow();
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java 19 makes [`ExecutorService implement AutoCloseable`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#close()), meaning it shuts down when exiting a try-with-resources block:

```java
try (ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)) {
   e.submit(task1);
   e.submit(task2);
} // blocks and waits
```

This is a [structured concurrency](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part2.html) approach developed as part of [Project Loom](https://openjdk.org/projects/loom/), which is incubating in Java 19.  As of July 2022, Java 19 is not officially released but early access builds are available.

Comment: The JDK implementation is good reference, but week in mind the close methods wait for all task completion, and `awaitTermination` is waiting for 1 day (repetitively).

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37443866/48136) is the proper one if you want to close in a timely fashion.