# How to stop this thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, threadpool

I implemented [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/discovery/GroupOwnerSocketHandler.java) class in my android code

I made the below change in the run method(replaced "true"):

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                // A blocking operation. Initiate a ChatManager instance when
                // there is a new connection
                pool.execute(new ChatManager(socket.accept(), handler));
                Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed())
                        socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
                pool.shutdownNow();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to stop this thread before I close the app. So I implemented threadName.interrupt(); method. But this doesn't interrupt the thread.

I am actually confused with the usage of thread pool executor. So I am not sure how to do this efficiently. How can I implement interrupting this thread? When interrupt method is called, I want to close the socket, shutdown the pool and stop the thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread thread = new Thread () {
boolean isRunning = true;

public void stopThread() {
    isRunning = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            // A blocking operation. Initiate a ChatManager instance when
            // there is a new connection
            pool.execute(new ChatManager(socket.accept(), handler));
            Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed())
                    socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            pool.shutdownNow();
            break;
          }
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
```

Try this code. and call thread.stopThread() whenever you want the thread to stop.

Comment: still wont exit if the `Thread` is blocked in the `socket.accept()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want close an Android thread, you can set a variable to control `run()`,because `run()` is end, the thread will be closed.

The code is something like:

```
final boolean istrue=true;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (istrue){
                //TODO  your work
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

If you want to close the thread, you only set `istrue=false`

Comment: I suggest you call it `isRunning` or something like that. The name of a variable should give an indication of its purpose.

Comment: thanks for your  suggestion,Barth.just do it   in my  code style!

Answer (score 0):

Just call `shutDownNow` to close the pool and try interrupt all the threads inside it. You can check the difference in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520189/difference-between-shutdown-and-shutdownnow-of-executor-service):

> - `shutdown()` will just tell the executor service that it can't accept    new tasks, but the already submitted tasks continue to run
> - `shutdownNow()` will do the same AND will try to cancel the already submitted tasks by interrupting the relevant threads. Note that if
>     your tasks ignore the interruption, shutdownNow will behave exactly
>     the same way as shutdown.

If you want to interrupt or cancel an specific thread. I suggest you to use `submit` with `Callables`, With this, you will me able to work with your `Future` object, then if want to cancel a task you've given an executor service, you can call `cancel(true)` on its associated `Future`. When your task detects an interrupt request, it should preserve the interrupted status by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.