# Stop thread that's already running

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, executorservice

I have two APIs: one starts the thread, and another stops the thread. I'm successfully able to start a thread by calling `/start` API, but I'm unable to stop already running thread by calling `/stop` API. Seems like `Executor#stop()` does nothing.

My `RestController`:

```
@Autowired
private Executor executor;

@RequestMapping(path = "/start", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> startLongTask() {
    executor.start();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/stop", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> stopLongTask() {
    executor.stop();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My `Executor`:

```
@Component
public class Executor {

    @Value("${threads.number}")
    private int threadsNumber;

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsNumber);
        executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadsNumber);
    }

    /**
     * Start.
     */
    public void start() {
        executorService.submit(() -> otherService.methodImExecuting());
    }

    /**
     * Stop.
     */
    @PreDestroy
    publicvoid stop() {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        try {
            if (!executorService.awaitTermination(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `methodImExecuting`:

```
@Component
public class OtherService {

    public void methodImExecuting() {
        List<SomeObject> dataList = repository.getDataThatNeedsToBeFilled();
        for (SomeObject someObject : dataList) {
            gatewayService.sendDataToOtherResourceViaHttp(someObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's important how the method `methodImExecuting` reacts to the `executorService` attempts to interrupt it, so we need to see that method

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I've added `methodImExecuting` to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can not stop a running thread which does not cooperate. There's a deprecated `destroy()` method for threads, but this will lead to a "bad" state of your VM.

The only possibility to end the Thread clean is to interrupt it. But to check for interruption is the task of the thread itself.

So your `methodImExcecuting` sould look like:

```
void methodImExecuting() throws InterruptedException {
    // it depends on your implementation, I assume here that you iterate 
    // over a collection for example
    int loopCount = 0;
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        ++loopCount;
        if (loopCount % 100 == 0) {
            if (Thread.interrupted())
                throw new InterruptedException();
        }
        ...
    }
```

It depends on your implementation how often you have to look if your thread was interrupted. But it's a fact that the call of `executorService.shutdownNow();` will only set the `interrupted` flag of all threads currently running in the executorService. To really interrupt the thread, the thread must itself check if the `interrupted` flag is set and then throw an `InterruptedException`

Answer (score 1):

Your running threads have to react to the interrupt signal

```
Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
```

Otherwise the sending of the interrupt signal has no effect.

Here you can find a good explanation: 
[Difference between shutdown and shutdownNow of Executor Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520189/difference-between-shutdown-and-shutdownnow-of-executor-service)