# ExecutorService shutdown not interrupt threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, interrupt-handling

I try repeat example from Bruce Eckel's book  "thinking in java":

```
    public class Car {
        private boolean waxOn = false;

        public synchronized void waxed() {
            waxOn = true;
            notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized void buffed(){
            waxOn = false;
            notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized void waitForWaxing() throws InterruptedException {
            while (!waxOn)
                wait();
        }

        public synchronized void waitForBuffing() throws InterruptedException {
            while (waxOn)
                wait();
        }
    }

public class WaxOff implements Runnable {
    private Car car;

    public WaxOff(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                System.out.println("wax off!");
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                car.buffed();
                car.waitForWaxing();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exit via interrupt");
        }
        System.out.println("Ending Wax Off task");
    }
}

public class WaxOn implements Runnable {
    private Car car;

    public WaxOn(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                System.out.println("wax on!");
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                car.waxed();
                car.waitForBuffing();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exit via interrupt");
        }
        System.out.println("Ending Wax On task");
    }
}

public class WaxOMatic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Car car = new Car();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executorService.execute(new WaxOff(car));
        executorService.execute(new WaxOn(car));
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But I have **incorrect** behavior of `ExecutorService`. When I call `shutdown` method threads not interrupt and contionue work.

But if I change this exampe and use

```
Future<?> submit = executorService.submit(new WaxOff(car));
```

And after delay call `submit.cancel(true`) - Thread is interrupt fine.

It seems that when you call `shutdown` executor must interrupt all threads and I must go to catch block(catch `InterruptedException`) but it not work.

Comment: use [shutdowNow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow())

Comment: PS, a little bit of reading the javadocs would have helped you here

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520189/difference-between-shutdown-and-shutdownnow-of-executor-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Executors.newCachedThreadPool` use `ThreadPoolExecutor` internally as thread pool.

[`ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown()):

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

[`ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow()):

> This implementation interrupts tasks via Thread.interrupt()

So you can use `shutdownNow` instead.