# ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow() not throwing InterruptedException in Thread

Tags: java, try-catch, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads, interrupted-exception

I am implementing a Transfer Server program which takes messages from clients (via console input) and then forwards it to some sort of mailbox.

To allow concurrent reception of several messages by different clients, I first created a class that implements the `Runnable` interface. Each of this class instances will handle the communication with exactly one client:

```
public class ClientConnection implements Runnable {

    //...

    //...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // prepare the input reader and output writer
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            Message message = new Message();
            String request = "";

            // read client requests
            while ((request = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("Client sent the following request: " + request);
                String response;
                if (request.trim().equals("quit")) {
                    writer.println("ok bye");
                    return;
                }

                response = message.parseRequest(request);
                if (message.isCompleted()) {
                    messagesQueue.put(message);
                    message = new Message();
                }
                writer.println(response);
            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("ClientConnection: SocketException while handling socket: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Client Connection was interrupted!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (clientSocket != null && !clientSocket.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {}
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I do have a parent thread which is responsible for starting and managing all the ClientConnection runnables:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    clientConnectionExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    while (true) {

        Socket clientSocket;

        try {
            // wait for a Client to connect
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection(clientSocket, messagesQueue);
            clientConnectionExecutor.execute(clientConnection);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // when this exception occurs, it means that we want to shut down everything
            clientConnectionExecutor.shutdownNow();  // force terminate all ClientConnections
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now according to [this Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520189/difference-between-shutdown-and-shutdownnow-of-executor-service), I would have expected that as soon as `shutdownNow();` is being called, an `InterruptedException` would be thrown within my `ClientConnection.run()` method, and there, it should print `Client Connection was interrupted!`. But this does not happen, so the catch clause seems never to be reached, the input reading loop just goes on.

I read in another Stackoverflow question that this might be related to some other codeline within the block seems to be consuming the `InterruptedException`, but there wasn't any particular information on what codeline could do that. So I am thankful for any hints.

Edit: It turns out that as soon as I manually exit the loop by typing "quit" on the client, the loop will quit and then, `Client Connection was interrupted!` will be printed. So somehow the exception seems to be ignored as long as the loop is running, and only handled afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle docs for `shutdownNow`:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

If you take a look into `ThreadPoolExecutor` sources, you will find out that `shutdownNow` interrupts threads with this code:

```
        void interruptIfStarted() {
            Thread t;
            if (getState() >= 0 && (t = thread) != null && !t.isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    t.interrupt();
                } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
```

Your `ClientConnection` doesn't check the flag `Thread.interrupted`. Due to information in the post, I can't figure out which method throws `InterruptedException`. Probably, some other method, for example, `readLine` of reader or writer, blocks the thread, because they use socket's `InputStream` and `OutputStream` and because it's obvious that socket's streams block the thread if data is not immediatly available.

For example, I wrote this code to test it:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket()) {
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                int dataByte = socket.getInputStream().read();
                System.out.println(dataByte);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

On OpenJdk-16.0.2 there is no actual interruption.

I see two possible solutions for your problem:

1. Check `Thread.interrupted` inside the `while` loop if you are sure that `Socket` doesn't block your thread.
2. If your are not sure, use `SocketChannel` in non-blocking mode instead of `Socket` for checking `Thread.interrupted` manually.

For the second way I tranformed my example into this:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try(ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open()) {
                serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));

                SocketChannel socket = null;

                while (socket == null) {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                        throw new InterruptedException();
                    }
                }

                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                socket.read(byteBuffer);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.limit()];
                byteBuffer.flip();
                byteBuffer.get(bytes);
                System.out.println(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted successfully");
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

It works.

Good luck with Java :)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I'm indeed sure now that the `readline()` is blocking everything. I did not know that blocking functions that cannot be interrupted actually exist in Java. 
So I followed your approach by also checking the `Thread.interrupted` flag at the while loop condition, one flaw with this is that it seems necessary that the client hits the enter key one more time to actually quit the client. So the loop condition evaluates to false one step too late. I will furtherly look into the `SocketChannel` class and see whether this fits my needs.

Comment: @BenjyTec Sounds like the thread is blocked one extra time at `readLine()`. So, as I said in the answer, according to my little research, there is no way to prevent this behavior with `Socket`. Besides, you would like to recommend you be carefull with reading and writing operations either for `Socket` or for `SocketChannel`, because it is not an efficient way. The problem is that you actually need a thread to operate with a connection. IO operations may be many times more slower than bussiness-logic ones. My advise is to read and write in separate threads.

Comment: And generally about `SocketChannel`. I highly recommend you to use `SocketChannel`, because it can act both in blocking and non-blocking mode. Therefore, `SocketChannel` and `ServerSocketChannel` can always replace old `Socket` and `ServerSocket` in your code. Moreover, you can use `ByteBuffer` with them which allows you to easly implement any functionality for internal buffers. Please, take a look into `ByteBuffer` too if you are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I would have expected that as soon as shutdownNow(); is being called, an InterruptedException would be thrown within my ClientConnection.run()

Your `messagesQueue` should be a `BlockingQueue`. So `messagesQueue.put(message)` will make you need to catch an `Interrupted` exception. So only when the thread is blocked in the `put` method(`queue` is full), you call `threadpool#shutdownNow`, then the thread will receive an `Interrupted` exception. In other cases, thread will not receive this `Interrupted` exception.

You can change `while ((request = reader.readLine()) != null)`  to `while ((request = reader.readLine()) != null && !Thread.interrupted())`.

Another solution is to maintain all client sockets, and close all client sockets when you need to close them,  this way, the client thread will directly receive an `IOException`:

```
        List<Socket> clientSockets = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket accept = serverSocket.accept();
                clientSockets.add(accept);
                executorService.submit(new ClientConnection(accept));
            }catch (Exception e) {
                for (Socket socket : clientSockets) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        //
                    }
                }
                //executorService.shutdownNow();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, your second approach looks promising. One question though, the `clientSockets` list ist going to bloat up over time, isn't it? Because it is going to contain sockets of clients that already disconnected hours ago.

Comment: Yes, you should have a special class(maybe call it ```ClientManager```..) to maintain all client sockets, remove the corresponding socket when a client is closed.