# how to use thread in bean in jsf

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, concurrency

In my web application that uses JSF, I have 100 records that is selected from the front end(using check box) and on clicking of a button , those selected 100 records needs to be initiated(it will create survey using RESTAPI call), which calls a method in bean that will make REST API call.

At present each record processed in a sequence and each record takes 20 sec on a average. so if I choose nearly 100 records I am getting request time out.. I am planning to call the method in bean using thread.. can you please tell how can I do? Method in the bean is initiatereview that takes reference number as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

A managed bean is, in the end, a POJO. So, your problem boils down to *how to use multiple threads to execute a similar task over different objects*, so in the end is a Java problem **rather than a JSF problem**. For this, you have to use the [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface. A brief example to accomplish this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean {
    List<String> records;
    //other fields, constructor, getters and setters...
    public void foo() {
        int poolSize = records.size();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        for (final String record : records) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //tasks to perform in the threads...
                }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Some notes to this example:

- `poolSize` value should not be `records.size()`, I just used this as example about creating a thread per work to perform. Note that you should create as many threads your server support. The real value of this variable will depend on result of your tests. I would recommend using 10 as initial value and then change it to measure the performance results.
- You may create a class that implements `Runnable` interface that will hold the task you want to accomplish instead of creating an anonymous class.

Note that this is a possible solution. IMO it would be better sending the list of records to a component that will process them, for example via JMS call. Then the component will call your restful service and other things it must do to process the record.

Comment: can you provide me an example for JMS? on click of commndbutton I am calling initiatereview method in a bean that has other methods also. initiatereview method takes an obj that is chosen as parameter. initiatereview method in turn calls another method in a class that makes RESTAPI call and email is sent. I need to do this in a thread. how can I pass parameter to a method in run.. can I use a class that implements runnable and in constructor pass the parameters..

Comment: @hemsush check here: https://blogs.oracle.com/soaproactive/entry/jms_step_2_using_the

Comment: Also see how to properly shutdown: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504172/how-to-shutdown-an-executor-service

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy you can use `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` to shutdown the executor, they are just two different ways to do it, the problem is when you do not shut it down causing leaks in your application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I did not mean that your solution is not the proper one, it was to show other existing solutions.