# Processing N threads in parallel and main threads exits in the end

Tags: java, multithreading, countdown

For some processing, `n` threads needs to spawned and runs in parallel. The main thread, which starts the processing should exit, after all the processing is done.

Here is the code snippet:

```
private void spawnThreads2(int n) throws InterruptedException {
  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(n);
  final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    final int id = i;
    new Thread(){
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000)); // represents processing, can throw any Exception
        } catch (Exception e) {} 
        finally {
          latch.countDown();
        }
      }
    }.start();
  }
  latch.await();
  System.out.println("all completed.");
}
```

The `countdown()` is done in the `finally` block, so in case any exception happens application does not hang.

1. Is this design good for creating threads and waiting for them? Is there possibility application can hang and never come out, because of the `await()`?
2. Is there a way we can achieve same functionality using `join()`? We can store all the instance of the threads and check for status and wait. Is that a good way to do this.

Comment: @Gavriel still `Is there possibility application can hang and never come out, because of the await()` is not clear from the above queation.

Comment: well if any of the threads would have an endless loop, for example, then that thread would not end, and then your app would not end of course

Comment: I prefer invokeAll   of ExecutorService. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612697/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-java-executor/34784526#34784526. If you didn't handle exception properly, Countdownlatch may wait.

Comment: Why are you holding onto the `main` thread?  Why not let it return?

Comment: BTW: You can have multiple Random in the same milli-second. You would get better off not using currentTimeMillis as a seed.  The default uses System.nanoTime() and a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `ExecutorService`. You can obtain one using n threads by calling:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( n );
```

Then, you can start a task as follow:

```
executor.submit( runnable );
```

At the end, you can stop executor by calling `shutdown()` method. Doing that, no task can be added anymore but all submitted tasks will be executed. You can also wait for shutdown:

```
executor.shutdown();

while ( !executor.isTerminated() ) {
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop is unnecessary. Rather set a long enough timeout and if it's still not finished, then force quit.