# Executors or threads keep program from shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

In my program some threads are created and given a `Task` that ends (so that thread should die), and I also have a `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` and `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`, I noticed that if I press a close button that I made:

```
@FXML private void handleExit(){
    gameManager.cleanup();
    Stage stage = (Stage)menuBarTopMenu.getScene().getWindow();
    Platform.exit();
    stage.close();
}
```

I don't get the `Process finished with exit code 0` in intelij.

So I even set those threads I mentioned to daemons and this is the cleanup:

```
public void cleanup(){
    updateTime.shutdown();  // it's Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor
    updateTime.shutdownNow();
}
```

But I still don't see the successful exit. Could it be because I didn't shut down the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`? I couldn't find a way to shut it down.

What other cleanup I should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shutdown an ExecutorService?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504172/how-to-shutdown-an-executorservice)

Comment: Examine a thread dump (or use a tool like visualvm) after you try to quit and see what is still running.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto it's not the service that I can't shut down, it's the `newSingleThreadExecutor`.

Comment: it's the same thing, it is simply a specific use case of what you have in the duplicate answer

Comment: I'd do a thread-dump to figure out what non-deamon threads are actually left running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it is exactly because you didn't call shutdown on newSingleThreadExecutor, but if you have other running threads they may also stop the app from quitting. To force VM to shutdown (all threads will be terminated) you can call `System.exit(0);`

you crate the Executor service as that:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

\\ use the service to do work
\\ to shutdown the service
service.shutdown();

\\ to wait till the service terminate
service.awaitTermination();
```

Comment: OK, it doesn't have a `shutdown` method, so how do you shut it down?

Comment: I read in another answer that `System.exit(0);` doesn't really shut down the program...

Comment: the service you obtain from the Executors has a shutdown method

Comment: But I don't use a service, I use: `private Executor XExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` and it doesn't want to do `ScheduledExecutorService service = XExecutor;`

Comment: sory, it should be: private `ScheduledExecutorService XExecutor = Executors.  newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();`

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Thanks.